# Import multiple Excel Files using BCP into a created Table in SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, powershell, bcp

I have created a Table with the name "Buchungen" with the following SQL sintax:

```
CREATE TABLE Buchungen 
    (
        Buchungsdatum Date,
        Produkttyp varchar(50) NULL,
        Workshopname varchar(50) NULL,
        Gutschein varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        IDkategorie int NOT NULL identity (1,1),
        Workshopdatum Date NULL,
        Gutscheineingeloest int NOT NULL,
        AnzahlTickets int NOT NULL,
        Artikelpreis decimal (18,2) NULL,
        Einzelpreis decimal (18,2) NULL,
        GesamtZahlungspreis decimal (18,2) NULL,
        GesamtRechnungspreis decimal (18,2) NULL,
        Kundenname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        EmailAdresse varchar(50) NULL,
        Bezahlart varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        BestellGebuehr decimal (18,2) NULL,
        UeberweisungsID varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        BuchungsID varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        BestellID int NOT NULL,
        AnbieterID int NOT NULL,
        Anbieter varchar(50) NULL,
        Workshopmonat int NULL
    )
```

**TASK:**

To import multiple Excel files in the Table "Buchungen" which has the same column structure as the table I have created in SQL.
Is it possible to use BCP command from cmd to import into this table multiple and by structure identical Excel files.
I have to automate it, so that the import runs automatically at a given time during the day. This part I have figured out with a Task in Task Scheduler, which runs a .bat File with my bcp code.

Here is the line of code that I wrote for the BCP tool for cmd for just 1 txt file:

```
bcp ExcelImportTraining00.dbo.Buchungen in "C:\Users\Desktop\01 Dell Latitude 5400\01 Main Folder\00 Excel to SQL\Demo\Products.txt" -SServerName -c -F2 -t"|" -T
```

I am fairly new when it comes to SQL and SQL Server, therefore would much appreciate your help.

**QUESTION:**
Is it possible to use bcp tool on multiple Excel files and import them all in a previously created matching table in SQL?

I have also tried to integrate the bcp in a loop and to iterate trough all files in my folder, but could not import the data in the Table in my Database.

Here is the loop that I wrote:

```
$source = ""C:\Users\Desktop\01 Dell Latitude 5400\01 Main Folder\00 Excel to SQL\Demo\"  

$files=Get-ChildItem $source  -Recurse -Filter *.csv |  

Foreach {           

bcp TMKPIReporting.dbo.Buchungen in $files=Get-ChildItem $source  -Recurse -Filter *.csv  -SServerName -T -q -c -F2 -t 

}
```

It gets executed but my table in SQL Server is empty.

Comment: You'll need to iterate through the files. Assuming you're using PowerShell to call `bcp` you'll be able to quickly find some resources on how to loop through all the files in a directory from a search.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but I am still struggling.
I came up with the following loop:

`$source = ""C:\Users\Desktop\01 Dell Latitude 5400\01 Main Folder\00 Excel to SQL\Demo\"

$files=Get-ChildItem $source  -Recurse -Filter *.csv |
 Foreach {
   bcp TMKPIReporting.dbo.Buchungen in $files=Get-ChildItem $source  -Recurse -Filter *.csv  -SServerName -T -q -c -F2 -t
   }`
It gets executed but my table in SQL Server is empty.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70773284/edit) your question to include the PowerShell code that you're trying to use. Comments aren't the place for that as you can see by the lack of formatting.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning ok. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a few different ways.

```
select * 
into SQLServerTable FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
    'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;HDR=YES', 
    'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

OR

```
Insert into SQLServerTable Select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
    'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;HDR=YES', 
    'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]')
```

If your table structure matches all the headers in your Excel files, you may consider saving each Excel file as a separate CSV file, and Bulk Insert all CSV files into your table, using a loop. Finally, you can combine all excel files into one single Excel file, using VBA, or CSV file, and import that into SQL Server.